# How do I get Vim to automatically load .vimrc config from the current directory?

Tags: vim, gvim

I have a few projects that need different commands for running, building and testing, so I've put a .vimrc file in each of the project directories that define mappings to some F buttons. In the vim help files it says:

```
'exrc' 'ex'             boolean (default off)
                        global
                        {not in Vi}
        Enables the reading of .vimrc, .exrc and .gvimrc in the current
        directory.
```

So I have that option enabled, but when I `:cd` into a directory, the .vimrc file is not loaded. If I write `:so .\.vimrc` then it loads fine. Why isn't it being loaded automatically?

---

I'm using gVim 7.3 x64 for Windows.

Comment: Automatically using a `.vimrc` file from the current directory is a **really bad** idea. That file could easily be from an archive that you had downloaded, and automatically sourcing it would allow whoever created that archive to run arbitrary code on your computer.

Comment: @qqx: I think I can keep that in mind, the same way I keep in mind not to execute binaries I don't trust :P

Comment: `set exrc` never worked for me. You could try [this plugin](https://github.com/thinca/vim-localrc). There are probably others on vim.org.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If 'exrc' is set, the current directory is searched for a file named `_vimrc`, `.vimrc` or `_exrc` *at startup*. This is not done every time you `:cd` to a new directory. See

```
:help .vimrc
```

Comment: Doesn't that make it sort of useless? :S At least for gVim. Is there a gVim.exe startup parameter I can use to choose startup directory? That way I could create one shortcut for each project. Or even better, maybe I could specify a vim config file in the application shortcut so I can avoid the `exrc` thing altogether. Google here I come

Comment: It doesn't help with gvim launched from your desktop or file manager, but it wasn't intended to help with that. What you need is something that loads a vimrc from the parent directory of the first file you open when starting gvim. In that case, you know that the file name will be passed as an argument, so you could test for that and source %:h/.vimrc. See the `:help` entries for `argv()` and `fnamemodify()`. I wrote a plugin for this that looks at the path of every file when it's opened and sources a project-dependent file of buffer-local settings.

Comment: Note that `exrc` is deprecated in Neovim due to security concerns.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion this is best variant :

```
if getcwd() =~ '^\(/my/safe/dir1/\|/my/safe/dir2/\)'
  set secure exrc
endif
```

Source from: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file
but fixed syntax

Answer (score 3):

In vim version 8.1^ there is a autocmd-event named **DirChanged** that you can use to eval your project specific `.vimrc`. Here is more detail about when this event is triggered:

```
DirChanged = Working directory has changed in response to the |:cd| or |:lcd| commands.
```

#### Working Example

I'm not an expert in vim-script but I created the following function that loads my project specific `.vimrc` file, once I `cd` into the project folder. Past this function into your main `~/.vimrc` file.

```
if !exists("*LoadProjectVimrc")
  function! LoadProjectVimrc()
    let vimrcFile = findfile(".vimrc", ".;")

    if !empty(vimrcFile)
      execute ":so" l:vimrcFile
      echom l:vimrcFile
    endif

  endfunction
endif
autocmd DirChanged * :call LoadProjectVimrc()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something you could try:

```
autocmd BufEnter{,other event} {full path to file} {do blah}
```

And you would put that into an auto command group:

```
augroup {name you want here}
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter{,other event} {full path to file} source {full path to vimrc file}
    autocmd BufEnter{,other event} {full path to file} {define mapping here}
    autocmd BufEnter{,other event} {full path to file} {do blah}
    autocmd BufEnter{,other event} {full path to file} {do blah}
augroup END
```

So you would put your settings here, this way if you're in a specific buffer those mappings will load.

I also recommend doing some BufLeave events in order to unset those mappings when you're not in those buffers, if you want.

would that work for your needs? I'm not sure exactly of what you need so I simply made a template for you. :)

As I showed, you can do it in various ways, you decide which is better for your needs. Sorry I'm not actually solving the underlying problem of that setting not working though. :(

Comment: I'm not sure if you're joking... I say in my question that that's exactly what I'm doing now.

Comment: @Codemonkey /facedesk 5 times. I missed that last part. Wait just a sec, I'm gonna edit my question to use autocommands (if I find an event to do that). :)

Comment: @Codemonkey OK I changed my answer. Would that work better for you?

Comment: I'd really like to know why the `exrc` isn't working like advertised though. Have I misunderstood what the option means?

Comment: OK, some things to check. Do you have `set exrc` in your actual .vimrc file? Also, instead of a .vimrc file, did you know you can also use a .exrc file for these customizations?

Comment: @Codemonkey Well garyjohn answered your question I guess. And my method is a workaround I guess. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, what I ended up doing was creating a shortcut for each of my projects and loading a project specific config file as a session file using `-S session.vim`.